Clamped gain in a laser diode
One of my professors had mentioned that, in a laser diode, after meeting the threshold current requirements the gain is clamped at threshold gain and that all additional excess carriers injected past this point are immediately extracted by lasing photons through stimulated emission. My confusion is, if threshold gain is when gain = loss, and the laser diode is clamped at threshold gain, how can we ever get laser diodes with gain of (for example) 20 dB, or anything greater than Pout = Pin? It would be helpful to get an explanation of this in reference to the progression of this LI chart as pump current increases.LI plot
